# How to check the filetype of an uploaded file on Cloud Storage for Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I've got a simple file upload system in my app that uploads a `.mp3` file to firebase. I would like to check to make sure the file being uploaded is definitely a `.mp3` file and is no bigger than 80MB. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code for uploading the files, at the moment:

```
private void getMixForUpload() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("mp3/*");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Your Mix");
    startActivityForResult(chooser, ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("DjMixes").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Uri downloadUrl = uri;


                        firebaselogourl = downloadUrl.toString();

                    }
                });
            }

        }); 
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this link your returned URI will lead you to all information you want about your file 
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically, you have to use [File Metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata). Considering that you are getting the reference right and everything about the upload process is right, here is the way to do what you want:

```
taskSnapshot.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
        long sizeMB = storageMetadata.getSizeBytes() / (1024 * 1024);
        String fileType = storageMetadata.getContentType();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle your error, something bad happened :( 
    }
});
```

Now that you have the size (in megabytes) and the content type you can just use a `if` statement like this:

```
if (fileType.matches("audio/mpeg")  && sizeMB < 80)) {
   //your file is a audio file congratulations
   //your file also is bellow 80mb, good :)
} else {
   //the above statement is not true
}
```

*As the OP pointed out it's much better to use the `.matches()` function, which, in this instance, is the only one that works.*

**NOTE:** If you planning on deleting the file from firebase storage in case it's bigger than 80MB or it's not an `mp3` file, I suggest that you do these things before uploading the files. Basically, check if your file is `mp3` and it's smaller than 80MB, then go upload it. It improves the flow of the program and it's, frankly, a better way to do it anyways.

Comment: sorry for the delay in marking was busy yesterday

Comment: @markharrop Sure, no need to apologize. Was just asking if my solution worked or not. Happy Coding :)